# Check for null value in DataGrid View Field when Assigning Variable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to assign a value to a string variable when making a change to a datagridview field. Unfortunately if it's blank, it crashes with a NullReferenceException even if I try to check if it's null. I also don't know of a more efficient way to write this.

```
string change = "";
if (dgGroups[cid, rid].Value.ToString() != null) //gets null reference exception if row/column is blank.
{
    change = dgGroups[cid, rid].Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check should be like this. You are trying to call null.ToString() which is not valid and it will throw `NullReferenceException` .

```
string change = "";
if (dgGroups[cid, rid].Value != null)
{
    change = dgGroups[cid, rid].Value.ToString();
}
```

If you are using C# 6.0 you can write

```
string change = dgGroups[cid, rid].Value?.ToString();//this will return null if Value is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `??` operator:

```
change = (dgGroups[cid, rid].Value ?? defaultValue).ToString();
```